# Why is localStorage not saving my data on reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

When I reload the site, the state is reverted back to a empty array.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import History from './History'

const LOCALSTORAGEKEY = './finance/src/app/12321'; 

function App() {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);
  const amnt = useRef();
  const item = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    const stor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGEKEY));
    if (stor) setHistory(stor)
  },[])
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(history){    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(history))
    localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGEKEY,JSON.stringify(history))
    }    
  },[history])
  const now = new Date(); 

  const handleNewamnt = () =>{
    
    setHistory(prev=>{
      return([...prev, {'id':item.current.value ,'item': item.current.value, 'amnt': amnt.current.value, 'date': JSON.stringify(now) }]);
    })

    item.current.value = ''
    amnt.current.value = ''
  };


  return (
    <>
      <History  history_object= {history}/>

      <input placeholder='amount' type='number' ref={amnt} />
      <input placeholder='item' type='text' ref={item} />
      <button onClick={handleNewamnt}>confirm </button>

    </>
      

  )
}


export default App
```

I've tried debugging by using console.log. What seems to happen is that the history is saved to local storage properly, and retrieved from local storage properly. However, it seems that history somewhere is getting set back to an empty array after its retrieved from local storage.

Comment: Try `if (history && history.length)` in that second effect.

Comment: I agree with @Andy. In that second `useEffect`, when the component loads, it'll set your `localStorage` to the initial state of `history` which is an empty array. Adding a `length` like Andy suggested could resolve this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Only Check this condition in your second useEffect, I think checking `history && history.length` is done the work but it's adding one extra condition in it.

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    if(history.length){    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(history))
    localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGEKEY,JSON.stringify(history))
    }    
  },[history])
```

Comment: @Trevor Clute....